# Is it ok if a method returns a new instance of the class it's in?

Tags: design

I have a class called MyClass and a method called Get that looks something like this:

```cs
public class MyClass{
    string ClassVariable1 {get; set;}
    string ClassVariable2 {get; set;}
    string ClassVariable3 {get; set;}

    public MyClass Get()
    {
           ..set variable1, variable2, and variable3..

                return new MyClass()
                {
                    ClassVariable1 = variable1,
                    ClassVariable2 = variable2,
                    ClassVariable3 = variable3
                };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with doing this from a design perspective? Or any other perspective?

I guess to make this more clear, I'll post my actual code. I'm writing a facebook app and my class is called "FacebookAccount". The idea is that this will hold stuff related to a facebook account, like screen name, user email, recent status updates made by the user, etc.

```cs
class FacebookAccount
{
    public AccessToken AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string ScreeName { get; set; }
    public long FacebookUserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<StatusUpdate> ScheduledStatusNotPosted { get; set; }
    public List<StatusUpdate> StatusPosted { get; set; }
    private Facebook Facebook { get; set; }

    public List<FacebookAccount> Get(string userId)
    {
        var facebookAccountList = new List<FacebookAccount>();

        using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
        {
            var facebookAccount = dc.FacebookAccounts.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);

            foreach (var account in facebookAccount)
            {
                var faceBook = new Facebook(account.UserId, account.UserId);
                facebookAccountList.Add(new FacebookAccount()
                {
                    AccessToken = new AccessToken() { Token = account.Token, TokenSecret = string.Empty },
                    Email = account.Email,
                    ScreeName = account.Email,
                    ScheduledStatusNotPosted = faceBook.GetScheduledStatusUpdates(),
                    FacebookUserId = account.UserId
                });
            }
        }

        return facebookAccountList;
    }

    public FacebookAccount Get(string userId, long facebookUserId)
    {
        using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
        {
            var facebookAccount = dc.FacebookAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId && x.UserId == facebookUserId);
            if (facebookAccount != null)
            {
                Facebook = new Facebook(facebookAccount.UserId, facebookAccount.UserId);

                return new FacebookAccount()
                {
                    AccessToken = new AccessToken() { Token = facebookAccount.Token, TokenSecret = string.Empty},
                    Email = facebookAccount.Email,
                    ScreeName = facebookAccount.Email,
                    ScheduledStatusNotPosted = Facebook.GetScheduledStatusUpdates(),
                    FacebookUserId = facebookAccount.UserId
                };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, I call that method "copy", as opposed to "clone".

Comment: like [String.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) in Java API?

Comment: or any other immutable classes.  `Integer.valueOf()` as a quick example.

Comment: It can be good or bad. It's certainly not automatically wrong. The real question is **why** did you write this method this way? Once we know what your goal is, then we can tell you if this is a good way of achieving it. I suspect it's fine and you should simply name it "copy" or "clone" rather than "get", but I don't know that for sure yet.

Comment: What are you doing differently in this function that you are not wanting to do in a constructor for the class?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc in Java clone() is defined as a deep copy. Maybe it's the same in C#?

Comment: @jwenting Java's clone is not defined to be a deep copy. Quoting documentation: "The precise meaning of "copy" may depend on the class of the object. [...] *By convention,* the object returned by this method should be independent of this object. [...] Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation." (emphasis mine). Clone is therefore recommended to be a deep copy, but this is left up to subclasses to decide whether or not it should be so. The default implementation is a shallow copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if it is "wrong," but it certainly doesn't look "right" to me. I don't know why you are doing what you are doing. It looks like you are creating instances, but it's unclear if these are new instances or copies.

If you are creating new instances, the usual way to do that is to use a static factory method. It's static so you don't have to have an existing instance to create a new instance.

```
    static public MyClass Create()
    {
        // set variable1, 2, 3...

        return new MyClass()
        {
            ClassVariable1 = variable1,
            ClassVariable2 = variable2,
            ClassVariable3 = variable3                          
        };
    }
```

If that is a copy method, then call it "Copy." Calling it "Get" makes no sense in either case.

Answer (score 2):

It's not uncommon to have methods that return the type of the class--how else would a clone function work?

However, that's not what you are doing here.  You have a class that returns a list of itself.  I do not believe this function belongs in your Facebook class.

Comment: Why do you believe this?

Answer (score 0):

Having methods return a new instance of their class is done for two reasons:

1. Copying or cloning the current object
2. Making the object immutable

The C# language makes Strings immutable by having each method with a string return type return a new instance of a string. This allows you to modify data on an object and store the result of that operation without modifying the original object --- programming without side effects, if you will.

More specifically to your question, the `FacebookAccount` class violates the Single Responsibility Principle: it is doing data access as well as stuff related to a Facebook account. It really seems like moving the data access methods to `FacebookAccountRepository` would be more beneficial here.